# CNF formula induction proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove the following theorem: Every proposition formula is logically equivalent to a formula in CNF.

As a hint, they say that this can by proven by an induction on the structure of the formula, this is what I have done so far:

Basis: A formula with just one symbol (propositional variable) is already in CNF.

Inductive step: A formula with more than 1 symbol has to be in one of these cases:

1) $$\varphi_1 \land \varphi_2$$
2) $$\varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2$$
3) $$\varphi_1 \rightarrow\varphi_2$$
4) $$¬ \varphi_2$$

Let's consider case 1: $\varphi = \varphi_1 \land \varphi_2$, as $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ have a CNF equivalent formula(by hypothesis, and let's call them $\varphi_1'$ and $\varphi_2'$), then:

$$\varphi = \varphi_1' \land \varphi_2'$$

Which is CNF, and this proves case 1.

Let's consider a formula with the following structure $\varphi = \varphi_1 \lor \varphi_2$. By hypothesis: $\varphi_1$ y $\varphi_2$ have CNF equivalents ($\varphi_1'$ and $\varphi_2'$), then:

$$\varphi = \varphi_1' \lor \varphi_2'$$

where:

$$ \varphi_1' = \psi_1 \land \psi_2 \land ... \land \psi_m$$
$$ \varphi_2' = \delta_1 \land \delta_2 \land ... \land \delta_n$$

And $\psi$ and $\delta$ are clauses of the form: $$\psi_i = L_1 \lor L_2 \lor ... \lor L_{k_i}$$

Applying distributive property on $\varphi_1'$:

$$\varphi_1' \lor (\delta_1 \land \delta_2 \land ... \land \delta_n)$$
$$= (\varphi_1' \lor \delta_1) \land (\varphi_1' \lor \delta_2) \land ... \land (\varphi_1' \lor \delta_n)$$

Doing the following on each $\delta_i$:
$$\delta_i \lor \varphi_1' = \delta_i \lor ( \psi_1 \land \psi_2 \land ... \land \psi_m) = (\delta_i \lor \psi_1) \land ... \land (\delta_i \lor \psi_m)$$

Thus, we get

$$ (\delta_1 \lor \psi_1) \land ... \land (\delta_1 \lor \psi_m) \land$$
$$ (\delta_2 \lor \psi_1) \land ... \land (\delta_2 \lor \psi_m) \land$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$ (\delta_n \lor \psi_1) \land ... \land (\delta_n \lor \psi_m)$$

This expression is in CNF, which proves case 2.

For case 3, we have $\varphi = ¬\varphi_1$. By hypothesis $\varphi_1$ has a CNF equivalent(which we'll define $\varphi_1'$).

$$ \varphi_1' = \psi_1 \land \psi_2 \land ... \land \psi_m$$

$$\psi_i = L_{i1} \lor L_{i2} \lor ... \lor L_{ik_i}$$

Then:

$$¬\varphi_1=¬(\psi_1 \land \psi_2 \land ... \land \psi_m)$$

$$= ¬\psi_1 \lor ... \lor ¬\psi_m$$

$$ = (¬L_{11} \land ... \land ¬L_{1k_1}) \lor$$
$$ \ \ (¬L_{21} \land ... \land ¬L_{2k_2}) \lor$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$ \ \lor (¬L_{m1} \land ... \land ¬L_{mk_m})$$

And here is where I am stuck. I was thinking on rewritting the last term, to get: $\varphi_1''\lor \varphi_2'' \lor ... \lor \varphi_m''$, and using case 2 to end this proof, however I don't know if I can do this. How should I proceed? (and what about the formalisms?)

best regards

Comment: I don't understand why they suggested you use induction.  You only need to prove that the last column of every truth table can get expressed in conjunctive normal form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

By (repeated) *Distributivity*, we have :

> $[(\psi_1 \land \psi_2) \lor (\sigma_1 \land \sigma_2)] \equiv [(\psi_1 \lor \sigma_1) \land (\psi_1 \lor \sigma_2) \land (\psi_2 \lor \sigma_1) \land (\psi_2 \lor \sigma_2)]$.

Thus, you have to simply "rearrange" the new disjunction of conjuncts (coming from the negation of the original conjunction of disjuncts by De Morgan) in order to produce the needed CNF.

Comment: got it! thanks, I don't know why I did not think that :O